# Create an error Dialog in Blender

Tags: python, dialog, popup, blender

i got a problem, i need to let a error dialog to come up when something happens

i just found this artikle : 
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Interface#An_error_dialog
but i dont really understand the code, i just need to put an simple error dialog on the screen, this may be the an example :

```
if .....
then let the pop up with this message come up : " .... "
else ........
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender uses operators to perform actions or tasks, in this example the `MessageOperator` is an `bpy.types.Operator` subclass that takes care of displaying the dialog. When it's `invoke()` is called it shows the dialog with `wm.invoke_popup()` passing `self` as the operator, which sets up it's draw function to handle displaying the contents in the dialog.

Later in `scanFile` the `MessageOperator` is created and invoked with

```
bpy.ops.error.message('INVOKE_DEFAULT', 
            type = "Error",
            message = 'Found "return" on line %d' % n)
```

The `bpy.ops.error.message` is constructed from `bpy.ops` as the container of all operators followed by `error.message` which is defined by `bl_idname` in the operator class. The two named values that are passed are stored in the class properties of `type` and `message` and are used when the dialog is displayed.

The `bpy.utils.register_class()` calls are used to register these newly defined classes within blender's data structure so that they can be used.

Blender's usage convention doesn't use popup dialogs like you get in most GUI applications. It is more common to pass notification or error messages to a user by using the operators [`report()` function](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.report). This displays a message in blender's header next to the logo.